# How to write a pandas dataframe into a single CSV file to a mounted s3 bucket in Databricks?

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks

I have found only resources for writing Spark dataframe to s3 bucket, but that would create a folder instead and have multiple csv files in it. Even if i tried to repartition or coalesce to 1 file, it still creates a folder.

How can I do df.to_csv() directly to the mounted s3 bucket?

Comment: If you convert it to Spark dataframe, you can use `df.write.csv('s3://bucket/path/')` -- make sure that the bucket is defined as an External Location with associated Credentials and Databricks will manage the access and authentication for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find how to write pandas directly into s3 as a single CSV file. There are guides suggesting boto3 and s3fs but those don't work with mounted s3 bucket on databricks.

Anyway, a workaround is possible:

First, write the pandas dataframe to DBFS as a CSV file.

```
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/EeAnn/Test.csv',index=False)
```

Then, copy the file to the mounted s3 location.

```
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/EeAnn/Test.csv', '/mnt/cloudcherrymount/Test.csv')
display(dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/cloudcherrymount'))
```